# xsd schema wont process file xml correctly

Tags: xml, xsd

i'm trying to load a huge xml file to db using sqlxml bulk loader. In order to do that, we have to update the schema file. Here is the schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
 xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema"
            xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0" >

  <xsd:element name="EagleML" 
               xsi:type="WarehouseTransactionMessage"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

                 sql:is-constant="1" >
    <xsd:complexType >
      <xsd:sequence>
  <!--<xsd:element name="header" sql:is-constant="1" />
  <xsd:element name="taskIdentifier" sql:is-constant="1" />-->
    <xsd:element name="warehouseTransaction" sql:is-constant="1">  
   <xsd:complexType >  
     <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="warehouseOpenLot" sql:relation="TEST"  >  
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="accountingBasis" type="xsd:string" />
              </xsd:sequence>
                <!--<xsd:attribute name="accruedLtdBase" type="xsd:decimal"  />
             <xsd:attribute name="accruedLtdLocal" type="xsd:decimal"  />-->
             <!--<xsd:attribute name="xrateLocalBase" type="xsd:decimal"  />-->
             <!--<xsd:attribute name="buySellFlag" type="xsd:normalizedString"  />
             <xsd:attribute name="closeTipsIncomeLtdBase" type="xsd:decimal"  />-->
         </xsd:complexType>  
        </xsd:element>  
     </xsd:sequence>  
    </xsd:complexType>  
  </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and here is the xml file

```
<EagleML
eaglemlVersion="2-0"
eaglemlType="WarehouseTransactionMessage"
eaglemlRevision="263"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0 eagleml-main-2-0.xsd"
xsi:type="WarehouseTransactionMessage"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0"
>
  <header>
    <messageId>B70JFJ55EE9AVXOX</messageId>
    <sentBy>http://www.eagleinvsys.com/</sentBy>
    <creationTimestamp>2017-09-25T08:25:54-04:00</creationTimestamp>
  </header>
  <taskIdentifier>
    <correlationId>JFJ55EE9TARJH009</correlationId>
    <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
  </taskIdentifier>
     <warehouseTransaction>
      <header>
        <objectType>WarehouseOpenLot</objectType>
      </header>
      <warehouseOpenLot>
        <accountingBasis>USTAX</accountingBasis>
      </warehouseOpenLot>
      <warehouseOpenLot>
        <accountingBasis>TESTT</accountingBasis>
      </warehouseOpenLot>
    </warehouseTransaction>
  </EagleML>
```

if if leave these tags off, it works fine but i dont have the luxury of doing that:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0 eagleml-main-2-0.xsd"
xsi:type="WarehouseTransactionMessage"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0"
```

What am i doing wrong here?I've tried moving these tags into the EagleML element but I still seem to be getting nowhere. Does anyone see the error in this?

Answer (score 0):

A schema describes the XML vocabulary of a particular namespace. If there is no targetNamespace attribute in the schema, it describes a no-namespace vocabulary.

Your instance document has the namespace declaration xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0", which puts EagleML and all its children/descendants into that namespace, which is not the targetNamespace of the schema.

Without knowing anything about the specification of EagleML, I don't know whether it's the schema or the instance document that is wrong, but I can tell you that they don't match. The simplest fix is to add a targetNamespace attribute to the xs:schema element.